# Proof Check: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ be a continuous function...

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

For the following question, is my proof correct? Can I write it any better?

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ be a continuous function such that $\gamma(0) \ne \gamma(1)$. Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(\gamma(0)) = 1$ and $f(\gamma(1)) = 0$. Prove that $[0,1] \subset f(X)$.
>
> > Proof. Notice that $g := f \circ \gamma$ is a continuous function on a connected set. Further notice, that $\forall k \in (0,1)$,
> > \begin{equation}
> > \inf\big\{g(x): x \in [0,1]\big\} \le 0 < k < 1 \le \sup\big\{g(x): x \in [0,1]\big\}.
> > \end{equation}
> > Hence, it follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem that $\exists \tilde{k} \in (0,1)$ such that $g(\tilde{k}) = k$. Finally, we have that $g(0) = 1$ and $g(1) = 0$. Thus,
> > $$[0,1] \subset g\big([0,1]\big) \subset f(X)$$

Comment: Hello. It seems good to me. You can be more concise by saying that the image of a connected set by a continuous map is a connected set. Now every connected set of $\mathbb R$ is an interval ; as $0$ and $1$ are in this image, we deduce that $[0,1]$ is contained in it (this is exactly the statement of the Intermediate Value Theorem so your proof is correct).